# How to populate a select from mysql using Ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have an empty select in HTML that i want to populate through the database.

I have a button that opens a Modal and passes an id. With that ID i fetch the Data from the database and fill all the form fields for one company. However a company can have multiple employees, so i want to fill a select so that all employees that have the same ID as the company, will be shown.

For example:

Company ID is 43, i fill all the form fields (name, location etc.) using this id and fetching the data from the database.
In the table employee there are 3 employees that have the ID 43 as FK, let's name them hans, max and peter.
Now i want to populate a select that shows all 3 of them, so that an user can select one of them and depending on that selection an empty form will be populated, so that it can be edited.

I'm assuming this involves a loop, but i'm not sure how to do it. Not sure if it's relevant but all my mysqli calls use prepare, as i've read this is more secure.

The loop i've tried so far is this, but it's not working. I'm not sure if it's the loop that isn't working or if i'm trying to populate the select wrong.

This is inside a select and all the input fields get populated.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$prename= $row['prename'];
$surname= $row['surname'];

$users_arr[] = array("prename" => $prename, "surname" => $surname);
}
```

Then i return the data as follows

```
echo json_encode(array('users_arr'=>$users_arr));
```

and try to populate the select in the AJAX success

```
$.each(data.users_arr, function(key, val){ 
$("#contact_persons").append('<option id="' + data.prename + '">' + data.surname + '</option>');
});
```

Thanks

Edit: The complete Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",    
            error: function () {


                    $('#alertdone').removeClass('hidden');



        },
        //if ajax call is successful populate form fields and hide error message
        success: function (data) {


            //hide error message
            $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');


                $.each(data.users_arr, function(key, val){ 
                $("#contact_persons").append('<option id="' + data.prename + '">' + data.surname + '</option>');
                });


            }


        });
    });
```

Comment: you've set it in PHP side as `prename` and `surname`, why are you accessing it as `cp_prename` and `cp_surname` in the response (JS success block)?

Comment: @Ghost

That's a mistake on my part. I edited the code to make it simple. Forgot to edit that part. It's not the reason it's not working.

Comment: The Javascript is a bit of a mess. You loop through the `users_arr` but you're not using `key` and `val`. It is the `val` that contains the `prename` and `surname`.

Comment: Check my answer below. @zoefrankie

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

Would i do val.prename and val.surname then? When doing that i get an error message in the browser console.

Comment: I cannot react if I don't know what the error message is. Have you inspected the content of `val` with the debugger in the web development tools?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

My bad. The error message was " SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

I have inspected the content of val but it says undefined in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX success you can try

```
var d = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(d.users_arr, function(index, element) {
$("#contact_persons").append('<option id="' + element.prename + '">' + element.surname + '</option>');
});
```

### Edit

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",    
            error: function () {
                    $('#alertdone').removeClass('hidden');
             },
            success: function (data) {
             //hide error message
            $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');
            var d = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(d.users_arr, function(index, element) {
            $("#contact_persons").append('<option id="' + element.prename           + '">' + element.surname + '</option>');
            });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This returns 
    SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data in the browser console

Comment: This returns the same error message " SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: What do you mean? This is the data that php returns to the ajax call, isn't it?

echo json_encode(array('users_arr'=>$users_arr));

Comment: Try putting a die() after your echo json_encode in PHP code.